# Testing second condition when first false

Tags: python

I have a simple program

```
temp='abc12a'
ver = 1
print(temp[-1].isdigit())
if temp[-1].isdigit() & int(temp[-1])!=ver:
    print(temp[:-1]+t)
```

which gives the output

```
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 3, in <module>
  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Why does the second condition even get checked when the first is false? Is there a way to only do the second if the first is true that is cleaner than two ifs?

Comment: the operator you are using is logical and. use `and`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `&` operator in Python checks as a bitwise and. It does not short circuit.  The `and` operator properly short circuits, which is the behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The boolean connectives are `and`, `or` and `not`.

`&` is a bitwise and.

### From [5.10. Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

```
or_test  ::=  and_test | or_test "or" and_test
and_test ::=  not_test | and_test "and" not_test
not_test ::=  comparison | "not" not_test
```

In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. (See the [`__nonzero__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) special method for a way to change this.)

The operator `not` yields `True` if its argument is false, `False` otherwise.

The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

(Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument. This is sometimes useful, e.g., if `s` is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression `s or 'foo'` yields the desired value. Because not has to invert a value anyway, it does not bother to return a value of the same type as its argument, so e.g., `not 'foo'` yields `False`, not `''`.)